# Configure VirtualBox to run three Server under one private domain

Tags: networking, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, virtualbox, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to setup VMs on VM VirtualBox. The ultimate goal is to create SharePoint 2013 Development environment. I want private network with DNS ... Active Directory Server running on window server 2012, another VM running SQL Server Database and 3rd VM running SharePoint. Networking and Server configuration is new area to me so I am struggling with these topic.

Now I have install window server 2012 with adopter 'Internal Network' without DHCP (Disable) and give static IP address to this window, but then I don't have internet access and it case undefined network.
My first step is to install Active Directory on this within a domain and put SQL database server and SharePoint Server under the main domain.

I need guideline.!! is my steps are correct??

Many Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you do not want this test network to have access to the interenet as it could cause disruption in your production network. I have a dev Sharepoint 2013 environment with VirtualBox using server 2008 r2.

I created a host-only network in VirtualBox v4.3 ( I think there is one by default ). I configured it to not have dhcp, as my test DC would handle that for me, under File > Preferences > Network > VirtualBox Host-Only Adpater. Assigned that adapter and only that apdapter to my VM's. I was able to have the machines communicate to eachother and to the host. I used the host to do any required downloads and then pass them to the VM's using the C$ shares or shared folders i configured on the VM settings. More importantly i dont have to worry about other computer finding my Dev DHCP server.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly

Comment: did you install Active Directory?? for sharePoint

Comment: I was making a test domain, in my case, so yes. I believe ActiveDirectory is required for at least the service accounts in SharePoint2013 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx

The installation will fail on step 2 if you do not have ActiveDirectory installed.

Comment: I have managed to bypass this by using local account; need to run powershell to override this part.

Comment: Good to know. You should include the powershell snippet here.